# Remove lines in a string that start with certain characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, text, nlp

I am trying to remove all lines in a string that start with some characters. I tried the block of code below but it was not working. My code should only print `"Any thanks`" as the result, but it outputs the entire original text.

```
text = """Any thanks \n first_************ \n last_************ has \n"""

from io import StringIO
s = StringIO(text)
for line in (s):
    if not line.startswith(' first_') \
        or not line.startswith(' last_'):
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every string will fullify that `or` as those two conditions are mutually exclusive - compose your condition with `and`:

```
if not line.startswith(' first_') \
    and not line.startswith(' last_'):
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `or` statement is always returning `True`. For example if the line starts with `' first_'` then `not line.startswith(' first_')` returns `False` and `not line.startswith(' last_')` returns `True` so. `False or True` evaluates to `True`.

There are a couple ways you could write this, but the most straightforward would be to rewrite the if statement:

```
for line in (s):
    if not (line.startswith(' first_') or line.startswith(' last_')):
        print(line)
```